# Use Stack Overflow as a question repository

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently became responsible for watching a bit over the development of an open source Python project for scientific computing which is gaining some traction outside of the immediate vicinity of our research group. I am trying to figure out what is a best way to tackle the question cycle.

Would it make sense to encourage users to ask their question predominantly on Stack Overflow? Then I could watch when questions appear and answer them. At the same time recurring questions would be available to future users.

Note: the code is on a GitHub repository where we track issues and there is also a Wiki.

Comment: A question can be deleted with enough votes from the community.  You really should not use Stack Overflow has an external help site for your own software

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of that. But this contradicts the answer in the duplicate to this question, where the example from Android is given.

Comment: It really doesn't. From the answer on the duplicate: "But Stack Overflow should only be ONE of the options available." under the bullet headed "Start with your support pages". Also, from the linked Android page, "It's also important to point out that we don't plan to change the android-developers group" -- they continue to support Android developers on their site(s), allowing Stack Overflow to be one input among many (in Android's case, for beginning developers).

Comment: Well, one can of course interpret the sentence in this way. But "But Stack Overflow should only be ONE of the options available." is a very vague formulation and actually an almost void statement. Furthermore, it says "so issues like bug reporting, feature requests, and generalized discussions do not fit our Q&A format. The company should continue providing this type of support directly through their website." . This can be interpreted as: yes, Stack Overflow is fine for all technical Q&A, but other formats are needed for other types of questions.